# How to specify lifetime bounds for a closure involving references to intermediate local variables?

Tags: generics, reference, rust, lifetime

I'm trying to write a function like the following in Rust:

```
fn double_and_square<'a, T>(x: &'a T) -> /* whatever the output type of `&t * &t` is */ {
    let t = x + x;
    &t * &t
}
```

I want it to work on types where `T` is non-`Copy`. I need to specify not only that `&'a T` implements `Add` (easy), but also that a reference to its output type with the lifetime of local variable `t` implements `Mul`.

**Attempt #1** (no lifetime specified for the intermediate type):

```
fn double_and_square<'a, T>(x: &'a T) -> <&<&'a T as Add>::Output as Mul>::Output
where
    &'a T: Add,
    &<&'a T as Add>::Output: Mul,
{
    let t = x + x;
    &t * &t
}
```

Results in the following compiler error:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     &<&'a T as Add>::Output: Mul,
  |     ^ expected lifetime parameter
```

**Attempt #2** (alright, I'll add a lifetime specifier):

```
fn double_and_square<'a, 'b, T>(x: &'a T) -> <&'b <&'a T as Add>::Output as Mul>::Output
where
    &'a T: Add,
    &'b <&'a T as Add>::Output: Mul,
{
    let t = x + x;
    &t * &t
}
```

Results in the following compiler error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/main.rs:8:13
  |
8 |     let t = x + x;
  |             ^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 3:1...
 --> src/main.rs:3:1
  |
3 | / fn double_and_square<'a, 'b, T>(x: &'a T) -> <&'b <&'a T as Add>::Output as Mul>::Output
4 | | where
5 | |     &'a T: Add,
6 | |     &'b <&'a T as Add>::Output: Mul,
... |
9 | |     &t * &t
10| | }
  | |_^
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected &T, found &'a T)
 --> src/main.rs:8:13
  |
8 |     let t = x + x;
  |             ^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'b as defined on the function body at 3:1...
 --> src/main.rs:3:1
  |
3 | / fn double_and_square<'a, 'b, T>(x: &'a T) -> <&'b <&'a T as Add>::Output as Mul>::Output
4 | | where
5 | |     &'a T: Add,
6 | |     &'b <&'a T as Add>::Output: Mul,
... |
9 | |     &t * &t
10| | }
  | |_^
note: ...so that the type `<&T as std::ops::Add<&'a T>>::Output` is not borrowed for too long
 --> src/main.rs:9:10
  |
9 |     &t * &t
  |          ^^

error[E0490]: a value of type `<&T as std::ops::Add<&'a T>>::Output` is borrowed for too long
 --> src/main.rs:9:10
  |
9 |     &t * &t
  |          ^^
  |
note: the type is valid for the lifetime 'b as defined on the function body at 3:1
 --> src/main.rs:3:1
  |
3 | / fn double_and_square<'a, 'b, T>(x: &'a T) -> <&'b <&'a T as Add>::Output as Mul>::Output
4 | | where
5 | |     &'a T: Add,
6 | |     &'b <&'a T as Add>::Output: Mul,
... |
9 | |     &t * &t
10| | }
  | |_^
note: but the borrow lasts for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 3:1
 --> src/main.rs:3:1
  |
3 | / fn double_and_square<'a, 'b, T>(x: &'a T) -> <&'b <&'a T as Add>::Output as Mul>::Output
4 | | where
5 | |     &'a T: Add,
6 | |     &'b <&'a T as Add>::Output: Mul,
... |
9 | |     &t * &t
10| | }
  | |_^
```

The way that I read `the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'b as defined on the function body` tells me the compiler thinks `'b` is supposed to live as long as or longer than the whole function body, whereas I just want it to mean "any lifetime".

Is what I'm trying to do even possible in Rust? If not, are there any proposed changes I should watch that will make it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buckle up...

```
use std::ops::{Add, Mul};

fn double_and_square<'a, T, R>(x: &'a T) -> R
where
    &'a T: Add,
    for<'b> &'b <&'a T as Add>::Output: Mul<Output = R>,
{
    let t = x + x;
    &t * &t
}
```

Easy enough, right? ;-)

Let's take it step by step...

1. You wish to take in a reference to a type, but the *reference* needs to implement `Add`. `where` clauses let you write complex types on either side of the `:`, so we use `&'a T: Add`.
2. This will return some value that we take another reference to. However, the *caller* of `double_and_square` cannot specify the lifetime, since it only exists inside the function. This means we need to use a *higher-ranked trait bound*: `for <'b>`.
3. We have to use the type of the output of the `Add` operation, say that it implements `Mul`, and the output type is the generic `R`.

---

I'd recommend not taking references in the original function as it's way easier to understand:

```
fn double_and_square<T, R>(x: T) -> R
where
    T: Add + Copy,
    for<'a> &'a T::Output: Mul<Output = R>,
{
    let t = x + x;
    &t * &t
}
```

`&Foo` *is* a separate type from `Foo` and can be passed as the concrete type of `T`, so this should be able to be used in any place the original was, and probably usable in even more cases.

> I want it to work on types where `T` is non-`Copy`

Immutable references to types are always `Copy`, even if the type itself doesn't implement `Copy`. Thus, you can call this function with e.g. `T = i32` **or** a `T = &NonCopy`. The original case that *only* accepted references would only accept the second one.

In an ideal world, you'd be able to avoid the generic type `R` and just say `<...something...>::Output`, but as far as I know that's not currently possible.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know "HRTBs" were a thing. They do exactly what I was hoping for; thank you!
Also, is there a name for that `Output = R` syntax? Even in cases where it's not required like this, it'll seriously clean up some of my generic code with complicated return types and I want to read more about it.

Comment: Also, note, the non-reference version requires `T: Copy` but my original requirements explicitly stated I wanted to support non-`Copy` types.

Comment: @JoBates hmm. I think I'd just say that it's "specifying the associated type". The downside of such a syntax is that it's kind of a "lie" in this case. The caller of the function cannot actually pass a second generic type to constrain the call, like you would in a situation like `Iterator::collect`.

Comment: @JoBates that's not a real "requirement" in this case, see my last update. Different generics are happening here.

Comment: oh, of course; you're right. I'm in a different frame of mind because in the code I'm really working on, the argument type (reference or not) is a `SpecificGenericStruct<T>`, not simply `T`. I was just trying to remove extraneous details from the core question.