# Rust Callback: Error: Lifetime 'static required

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to write a generic function that takes a callback as a parameter. However, I always get the following error message:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `C` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:36:5
   |
17 | pub fn helper<'de, Q, S, C>(mut state : State, callback : C) -> Box<HandlerFuture>
   |                          - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `C: 'static`...
...
36 |     Box::new(f)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...so that the type `futures::Then<futures::stream::Concat2<hyper::Body>, futures::FutureResult<(gotham::state::State, hyper::Response), (gotham::state::State, gotham::handler::HandlerError)>, [closure@src/lib.rs:24:15: 34:10 callback:&C, state:gotham::state::State]>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/lib.rs:36:5
   |
36 |     Box::new(f)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is a minimal compilable example that produces the error message:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate gotham;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate mime;
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

use futures::{future, Future, Stream};
use gotham::handler::{HandlerFuture, IntoHandlerError};
use gotham::http::response::create_response;
use gotham::state::{FromState, State};
use hyper::{Body, StatusCode};
use mime::APPLICATION_JSON;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::{from_str, to_string};

pub fn helper<'de, Q, S, C>(mut state : State, callback : C) -> Box<HandlerFuture>
    where Q : Deserialize<'de>,
          S : Serialize,
          C : Fn(Q) -> S
{
    let f = Body::take_from(&mut state)
        .concat2()
        .then(|full_body| match full_body {
            Ok(valid_body) => {
                let body_content = String::from_utf8(valid_body.to_vec()).unwrap();
                let body_json = from_str::<Q>(&body_content).unwrap();
                let resp_json = callback(body_json);
                let resp_content = to_string(&resp_json).unwrap().into_bytes();
                let res = create_response(&state, StatusCode::Ok, Some((resp_content, APPLICATION_JSON)));
                future::ok((state, res))
            }
            Err(e) => return future::err((state, e.into_handler_error()))
        });

    Box::new(f)
}
```

Adding `C : 'static` to the `where` clause as rustc suggests, I get the following error message:

```
error[E0597]: `body_content` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:28:48
   |
28 |                 let body_json = from_str::<Q>(&body_content).unwrap();
   |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
33 |             }
   |             - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'de as defined on the function body at 17:1...
  --> src/lib.rs:17:1
   |
17 | / pub fn helper<'de, Q, S, C>(mut state : State, callback : C) -> Box<HandlerFuture>
18 | |     where Q : Deserialize<'de>,
19 | |           S : Serialize,
20 | |           C : Fn(Q) -> S,
...  |
37 | |     Box::new(f)
38 | | }
   | |_^
```

This is the minimal content of my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
futures = "0.1"
gotham = "0.2"
hyper = "0.11"
mime = "0.3"
serde = "1.0"
serde_json = "1.0"
```

Comment: Why do you believe that your code should work? Does your returned value capture that reference? Does the reference live long enough? How would the compiler verify that?

Comment: Why did you decide to take a reference in the first place?

Comment: @Shepmaster I believe my code should work because it does work just fine if I don't take a callback but call a function instead. I don't know where you ask me why I take a reference, if it is the parameter of `callback`, changing it to `Fn(Q)` instead of `Fn(&Q)` does not make any difference

Comment: I'm asking why you are taking `&Fn`. How long does *that* reference live? How can the compiler verify it lives long enough?

Comment: @Shepmaster Well, if I don't take a reference, I get an error message that the size of the callback is not known at compile-time (`the trait bound \`for<'r> std::ops::Fn(&'r Q) -> S + 'static: std::marker::Sized\` is not satisfied`)

Comment: But why don't you take a callback by value, [the way the books suggests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch13-01-closures.html#storing-closures-using-generic-parameters-and-the-fn-traits)?

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks, I tried that, but it still doesn't work. Please see my edit

Comment: I believe this is now a duplicate of [How to specify generic function bounds involving the lifetimes of intermediate variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49341520/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster it might be me but I cannot find how the other question/answer applies here. Would you mind elaborating on how the other answer helps me in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the help of rustc's suggestions and [this article](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html), I was able to solve all errors:

1. I added `C : 'static` to the `where` clause
2. I changed the closure `|full_body|` so that it would `move`
3. I changed the type bound from `Deserialize<'de>` to `DeserializeOwned`

I ended up with this code that seems to work:

```
pub fn helper<Q, S, C>(mut state : State, callback : C) -> Box<HandlerFuture>
    where Q : DeserializeOwned,
          S : Serialize,
          C : Fn(Q) -> S,
          C : 'static
{
    let f = Body::take_from(&mut state)
        .concat2()
        .then(move |full_body| match full_body {
            Ok(valid_body) => {
                let body_content = String::from_utf8(valid_body.to_vec()).unwrap();
                let body_json = from_str::<Q>(&body_content).unwrap();
                let resp_json = callback(body_json);
                let resp_content = to_string(&resp_json).unwrap().into_bytes();
                let res = create_response(&state, StatusCode::Ok, Some((resp_content, APPLICATION_JSON)));
                future::ok((state, res))
            }
            Err(e) => return future::err((state, e.into_handler_error()))
        });

    Box::new(f)
}
```