# Type arguments with block-level lifetime

Tags: rust, generic-type-argument

I have a fuction I want to supply with generic type arguments. However, in this case they require a specific lifetime (because of `serde::de::Deserialize<'de>`).

The type arguments are to be passed to a function, here called `run` within the function `myfunction`.
The argument `&data` is only alive for the lifetime of the `Ok(data)` block, which is in conflict of the lifetime `'b` of the generic type argument of `myfunction`.

If concrete types are supplied, this works right away, but as generic types are bound to the lifetime I'm not sure how to work around this.
Is there a way to specify the lifetime of the `Ok(data)` block or another way to supply the type arguments? Otherwise I'd have to have a `myfunction` variant for every type combination I need, which is possible, but not optimal or elegant.

I've put code with the functions that make this example run on the [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=e878ae78c897bf375b5d9b2af8311dc3).

```
//the function in question
fn myfunction<'b, T1, T2>(req: &'b [u8]) -> Result<(), ()>
where
    T2: TaskResult<'b>,
    T1: TaskInfo<'b, T2>,
{
    match extract_body(req) {
        Ok(data) => {
            // if concrete types are supplied, it works.
            //let t = run::<Test1, Test2>(&data);
            // as the generic types are bound to the lifetime 'b,
            // which is longer than data would live
            let t = run::<T1, T2>(&data);
            //do something with t
            Ok(())
        }
        Err(_) => panic!("error"),
    }
}

//can't be changed, as it is an abbreviated function of a crate I'm using.
fn extract_body(req: &[u8]) -> Result<bytes::Bytes, ()> {
    Ok(bytes::Bytes::from(req))
}
```

I hope there is a workaround for this.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How to specify lifetime bounds for a closure involving references to intermediate local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49341520/155423) and [How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35592750/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: See also [Lifetime error when creating a function that returns a value implementing serde::Deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43554679/155423)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll see if it works.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you, `serde::de::DeserializeOwned` seems to be the perfect solution. Didn't find even this after after looking for it for days!